# asp.net mvc reporting 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting

I think this question was asked for several times already, but since mvc is a new technology, I hope there is something new for it.

is there something good for mvc, to do reports ?

Comment: Version 3 is CTP, so I wouldn't necessarily call it a "new technology".  Also, its not really a component-centric technology, so you won't really find any "package" specifically written for MVC that does anything.  Any general works-with-html/integrates with IIS package would work.

Comment: @Will asp.net has 10 years, asp.net mvc has one, so I consider it new

Comment: @Will, so which technology would you recommend

Comment: well, if I knew I would have answered!  Unfortunately, I don't.  Just wanted to point out that if you search for specific to MVC you won't find much.  Also, specific-to-asp.net webforms might not work either, come to think of it; you'd have to be careful with that.

Answer (score 2):

If You need charts, use javascript. Something like [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/).

---

If you want to use rdlc`s, using mvc, it's still possible to generate them and serve as pdf`s available to download. Something like [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2006/03/02/How-to-render-client-report-definition-files-_28002E00_rdlc_2900_-directly-to-the-Response-stream-without-preview.aspx) I guess.

Comment: Thank you, but I need tables and stuff